# Clearing cookies after opening a browser

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having an issue where about 50% of the time I run my python selenium script, in only the first text box, it already has text displayed in the input (I believe because of cookies). What this means is that when I enter in my text using the `.send_keys()`, the text becomes invalid as I have two lots of text, so it cannot find the destination.

What is suppose to happen is that after typing in a text, it's item appears in a drop down list underneath, for which the script then selects. But if the text is incorrect, then obviously there is no item to select from in the list.

I thought I try a workaround of using `.clear()` to clear the textbox before typing in the text, but the drop down list doesn't appear (which is strange).

So really my question is that is there a way to ensure that the textbox is always empty every time i open the browser and run the script?

Below is little sample of a retrieving a text field, clearing it and then typing in the text (the workaround that didn't work).

```
depart_from = driver.find_element_by_id("departure-airport-input")
depart_from.clear()
depart_from.send_keys("Leeds Bradford")
```

Comment: If your send keys doesn't populate the drop down then probably your onchange event is not triggering..Please provide the DOM also JAVASCRIPT event that triggers the dropdown..

Comment: @sunderkandasamy I updated my question to include the html code and also the click event I use to try and select it

Comment: Maybe consider using the browser's keyboard shortcuts to accomplish your goal? For example, in Firefox you could send "Ctrl+A" to highlight all text once you focus on the text box element and then "Del" followed by your desired text.

Comment: Find the JAVASCRIPT class associated with ui-autocomplete and call it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Pre-select all text in the input and then type yours:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

depart_from = driver.find_element_by_id("departure-airport-input")
depart_from.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')  # Keys.COMMAND on Mac
depart_from.send_keys("Leeds Bradford")
```

If you want to check the input's text before sending the keys, use `get_attribute()`:

```
initial_value = depart_from.get_attribute("value")
if initial_value == FROM:
   # do smth
```

Comment: This little bug is annoying me so much. Now it's not clicking on the item from the list. If the browser opens and text isn't displayed, it does the above in your answer (which we can't see because there is not text to see to remove) and selects the destination from the list. But if the text does appear when browser opens, you can see it does what you stated but then it doesn't click on the item from the list

Comment: Only thing I can think of is type in the text and state in an if statement that if textbox does not equal FROM, then remove whole text and enter FROM in again. How do you do a not equal in python?

Comment: @BruceyBandit wait, what if you try to click into the input before sending ctrl+a? `depart_from.click()`?

Comment: @BruceyBandit updated with how to get the input value.

Comment: Thanks, still no luck, even with the click you stated. it just doesn't want to select the item after clearing existing text and typing it in again. Have you never came across this problem when you were testing on your end?

Comment: @BruceyBandit it's all use-case specific, difficult to tell without being able to reproduce the problem. Is this a public page? If yes, would be great to see your complete code right now so that we can be on the same page and I can experiment with it. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, I'll send you the code, also gives you an idea on the little bugs it is displaying in other pages (the only other bug which you know is meals page but I need to try and get that random drop down menu select working. Tbh with this application the only issue is this first page and the meals page drop down with the dom and this app (the toughest one) is done. Then there is that one we are looking at which is just get past the first plugin and that will be done ans the rest of the pages is same as this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104094/discussion-between-alecxe-and-bruceybandit).

Answer (score 0):

I know in Java it is as so...may be it'll give you some clues?

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```